# Imported custom xpath-function does not seem in Jdeveloper for OSB 12c

Tags: oracle, xpath, xquery, osb

I am importing custom xquery function to OSB 12c. I moved the resources these are jar file, custom-osb-xpath.xml and custom-osb-xpath.properties to "xpath-functions" folder. (C:\Oracle\osb\config\xpath-functions) But when i restart the Jdeveloper, it can't seem in my custom xquery function list. Why can't seem in xquery list? Is there any other configuration needed should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this directory you mentioned, xquery with custom-xpath will only work in the domain.
To also reflect on jDeveloper you must add the same files (xml and jar) in the directory:
[FMW_HOME]\soa\soa\modules\oracle.soa.ext_11.1.1